# It seems my request mapping is not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>`
</web-app>
```

Here is my servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cmpny.controller">   </context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
  p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

Here is my controller

```
package com.cmpny.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
public String sayHello(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");

    return "hello";
}
}
```

/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Greetings</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>``
```

After hitting the URL I'm getting below error

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M20
```

I'm using spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar. Please help me to get rid of this error. When I hit `http://localhost:8080/SampleApplication/` it works fine and displays the content from index.jsp. However, the error appears when I try `http://localhost:8080/SampleApplication/greeting.html`

Comment: I've copied your exact code, deployed it in Apache Tomcat 9 and got no problem obtaining the expected result: Hello World.

Comment: Hi Rubio, which version of java you used? 1.5 or 1.8? I just tried with 1.5 its working fine but not sure why I was unable to see the response before.

Comment: I've used java 1.8.0_77

Answer (score -1):

Following should work :

Changes in web.xml :

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Changes in controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting.html")
public String sayHello(Model model) {

// Do something

}
```

Comment: Hi Shinchan, thanks for your response, but its not working, I get the same response after making the changes

Comment: Ok. Check if you see any error related to spring application context initialization.

Comment: No I don't see any error. It works fine when I hit the http://localhost:8080/SampleApplication/ which renders my index.jsp. It only gives me 404 when i tried http://localhost:8080/SampleApplication/greeting.html but there is no errors i get on console. I suspect there any problem with mapping.